# Getting 403 (Forbidden), Microsoft Bot is trying to make a Web Client - download data call

Tags: c#, bots, http-status-code-403

I am trying to create a bot using Microsoft `BotFramework`

The issue I am facing is when the bot code is trying to download data(image which is uploaded by user to the bot) via any channel like Facebook messenger/Skype/Slack. The code to download is by creating a WebClient and making  a DownloadData call by passing the attachment URL.

I am able to browse the uploaded image URL. Also, the code for download data via web client works fine if I write a console application rather than a Bot application.

## c# Code snippet

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 
byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(imageUrl); // This line gives 403 error
```

Kindly suggest what should be the solution for this issue.

Comment: _downloading data works fine but when any image is uploaded via messenger [it] gives a HTTP 403 error if the same image is being downloaded_ - how can the same file be uploaded and downloaded at the same time?

Comment: The user uploads any attachment(say image) to the bot channel, and then for processing on the same image, bot code tries to download the data from the uploaded URL. Http 403 comes up when bot tries to download the data.

Comment: For Skype need to add DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization as ("Bearer", token) , DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept as "application/octet-stream"                    For any other channel: add DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept as content type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete fix for the issue:

```
    private async Task<IEnumerable<byte[]>> GetAttachmentsAsByteArrayAsync(Activity activity)
    {
        var attachments = activity?.Attachments?
        .Where(attachment => attachment.ContentUrl != null)
        .Select(c => Tuple.Create(c.ContentType, c.ContentUrl));
        if (attachments != null && attachments.Any())
        {
            var contentBytes = new List<byte[]>();
            using (var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl)))
            {
                var token = await (connectorClient.Credentials as MicrosoftAppCredentials).GetTokenAsync();
                foreach (var content in attachments)
                {
                    var uri = new Uri(content.Item2);
                    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        if (uri.Host.EndsWith("skype.com") && uri.Scheme == "https")
                        {
                            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(content.Item1));
                        }
                        contentBytes.Add(await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(uri));
                    }
                }
            }
            return contentBytes;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/662#issuecomment-232223965

you mean this fix? Did this work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

I am using BotFramework with Node.js and received the same error. 
Finally i found a workaround. I commented below lines in ChatConnector.js and its working fine for me now.

```js
if (isEmulator && decoded_1.payload.appid != this.settings.appId) {
       logger.error('ChatConnector: receive - invalid token. Requested by unexpected app ID.');
       res.status(403);
        res.end();
         return;
    }
```

if (isEmulator && decoded_1.payload.appid != this.settings.appId) {
                 logger.error('ChatConnector: receive - invalid token. Requested by unexpected app ID.');
                 res.status(403);
                 res.end();
                 return;
             }